# Text Within Polyline Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to be able to put text within my polyline like the embedded Google Maps does as you can see from the below screenshot...

[image: Google Maps Screenshot]

Now I have looked through the `PolylineOptions` API Reference and the `Polyline` but I can't see anything the points to achieving this. I really hope this is possible and I'm not going to have to hack something together.

Comment: Did you find a way too add a labal along or within a polyline? I ahve yet to find one myself.

Comment: @Canadaka I didn't find a way to do it exactly how I wanted but look at the accepted answer as this is the solution I chose.

Comment: Do we know if this is possible yet? I am trying to build a little hiking map with the trails named.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Post Worth look at, Describing how to add labels to polylines:

http://duncan99.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/google-maps-api-polylines-and-events/

Comment: This isn't as nice as I wanted it to be but it did let me put labels with the polylines

Answer (score 2):

I commented yesterday asking if there might be any current way to add text within polylines. I know this question has been resolved, but the last activity I can see was in 2014. 
I came across this library in github https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label

It allows a user to overlay text on the map with (see also examples folder):

```
    var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
        text: 'Route name',
        position: pointCoordinate,
        map: map,
        fontSize: 12,
        align: 'left',
    });
```

Note, their source code within the "onAdd" method applies the pane to the map level, meaning the text would be underneath polylines. So, instead, I added it to the floatShadow pane by:

```
panes.floatShadow.appendChild(canvas);
```

Instead of:

```
panes.mapPane.appendChild(canvas);
```

I was able to make my map look like:
[image]

Comment: Much appreciated.  I needed this exact feature as well, but could not find it in the maps API. I am using this same tool now, as well as your update to move the layer above the path. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding text to polylines is not (currently) supported by the Google Maps Javascript API v3.  You will need to create your own [custom overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) to implement that. (I doubt you can make the text "follow" the polyline along a curve easily)

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Its going to be a nightmare

Comment: Just f.y.i. there is a pre-made solution for adding simple text labels to maps, see: https://github.com/erunyon/ELabel but the drawback with that is of course you can't rotate text or curve it to follow lines. As @geo points out, a custom overlay would be the way to go, and I would think you would need to use <canvas> element, many tricks you can do with it, some googling along the lines of 'canvas curved text' or such.