# GeoXml3 - Custom Map Tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geoxml3

**SOLUTION**

> It seems I had some remnant code from the Google KML Layer and that
>   was hiding my Custom Tiles, not GeoXML3

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I'm wondering if it's possible to use custom images tiles with a GeoXml KML layer on top.

Currently, everything else on the map disappears when the layer is rendered.

The same happens with the Google KMLLayer unless you set 'preserveViewport' to true when creating the layer.

Anyone know if there's a similar option with GeoXML3?  Or how hard it would be to implement that feature?

Here's my map initialization code:

```
var centerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(66.722541, -140.625000);
var mapOptions = {
    center: centerCoords,
    zoom: 4,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['Atlas', 'Satellite', 'Road']
    }
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
map.mapTypes.set('Atlas', mapAtlas);
map.mapTypes.set('Satellite', mapSatellite);
map.mapTypes.set('Road', mapRoad);
map.setMapTypeId('Atlas');
```

Now, if I render using this it works okay, the KML comes out over my custom tiles:

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml',
        preserveViewport: true
    });
kmlLayer.setMap(window.map);
```

The important part is the 'preserveViewport' - without this everything except the KML layer will be hidden (My custom markers and tiles).

The same (everything gets hidden) happens using the GeoXml3 parser:

```
var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: window.map});
myParser.parse('cta.xml');
```

The KML file is the same.  I assume it's because there is no such 'prerenderedViewport' option with this?

Comment: What does your code look like?  Geoxml3 just translates KML to native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects, so if you custom map has strange coordinates, it might behave like that. But hard to say without seeing an example.

Comment: Cheers for the response.... It seems to be working perfectly now.  I think perhaps there was remnants of old Google KML code in there (without the prerenderedViewport option set). 
One last question, is it possible to use KML for Streetnames? And have the streetnames show up over the Polyline.  I don't think so, but I'd like confirmation from an expert!

Comment: **Update** Seems you already answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852326/text-within-polyline-google-maps-v3

Comment: This question is a mess. Please delete parts that you want to be disregarded. We can use history to view previous versions of the post.

Answer (score 1):

The option for geoxml3 that prevents it from zooming and centering the map on the data is:

```
zoom    boolean true
```

> If **true,** the parser will automatically move the map to a best-fit of the geodata after parsing of a KML document completes.

(It defaults to true as indicated above, set it to false to prevent that behavior)

> Referebce from **[geoxml3 Parser Reference](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/ParserReference)**