# Add marker with label in google map's every end of polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I've multiple polylines, I want a marker on every end and start of polyline with a label, I am tracking bike movement, I am getting the polyline but i need to display the time on poly line or on the end point, if i can show the time in the polyline it would be great. I am developing a tracking system, i am getting the lat long, of start and end points i am also abple to draw polylines, i want to display time on the polyline or at least display a marker on every end and show  the time... below is my code

```
    var bikearray = [];
    $('#searchbtn').on('click', function() {
     $.ajax({
        url:'http://metrobikes.in/api/a2b-bike-movement-on-map',
        method:"GET",
        data : {
            start_Date : "2017-12-11",
            end_date : "2018-01-24",
            bike_number : "KA-51-D-6109"
       },
    }).done(function(data){
        bikearray = data.result.data;
        initMap();
     });
});



function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.98966, 77.653637),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var lineSymbol = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
    };
    for(i = 0; i < bikearray.length;  i++){
        var from_lat = parseFloat(bikearray[i].from_lat);
        var from_long = parseFloat(bikearray[i].from_long);
        var to_lat = parseFloat(bikearray[i].to_lat);
        var to_long =parseFloat(bikearray[i].to_long);
        var linecolor = bikearray[i].colour;
        console.log(bikearray[i].from_lat);
        var bikePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path:  [

                {lat: from_lat, lng: from_long},
                {lat: to_lat, lng: to_long}
            ],
            icons: [{
                icon: lineSymbol,
                repeat:'35px',
                offset: '100%'
            }],
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: linecolor,
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            map: map
        });
        bikePath.setMap(map);


    }


}
```

Comment: There is no code to add markers to the polyline. What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

To add a marker to the beginning and end of the polyline, add a marker to the beginning point and to the ending point.  To add the time in an InfoWindow on the end marker, add that as well (and trigger a click on it to open it):

```
for(i = 0; i < bikearray.length;  i++){
    var from_lat = parseFloat(bikearray[i].from_lat);
    var from_long = parseFloat(bikearray[i].from_long);
    var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: {lat: from_lat, lng: from_long}
    });
    var to_lat = parseFloat(bikearray[i].to_lat);
    var to_long =parseFloat(bikearray[i].to_long);
    var endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: {lat: to_lat, lng: to_long}
    });
    var time = bikearray[i].time;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(endMarker, 'click', (function(marker, time, infowindow) { 
      return function(evt) {
        infowindow.setContent(time);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }})(endMarker, time, infowindow));
    google.maps.event.trigger(endMarker, 'click');
    var linecolor = bikearray[i].colour;
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gpwm08s6/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var bikearray = [{
    from_lat: 12.98966,
    from_long: 77.653637,
    to_lat: 12.9715987,
    to_long: 77.5945626,
    colour: "blue",
    time: "12:00"
  },
  {
    from_lat: 13.0826802,
    from_long: 80.2707184,
    to_lat: 12.9922145,
    to_long: 77.7159,
    colour: "red",
    time: "11:00"
  },
]

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.98966, 77.653637),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
  };

  for (i = 0; i < bikearray.length; i++) {
    var from_lat = parseFloat(bikearray[i].from_lat);
    var from_long = parseFloat(bikearray[i].from_long);
    var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: {
        lat: from_lat,
        lng: from_long
      }
    });
    var to_lat = parseFloat(bikearray[i].to_lat);
    var to_long = parseFloat(bikearray[i].to_long);
    var endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: {
        lat: to_lat,
        lng: to_long
      }
    });
    var time = bikearray[i].time;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(endMarker, 'click', (function(marker, time, infowindow) {
      return function(evt) {
        infowindow.setContent(time);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(endMarker, time, infowindow));
    google.maps.event.trigger(endMarker, 'click');
    var linecolor = bikearray[i].colour;
    console.log(bikearray[i].from_lat);
    var bikePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [

        {
          lat: from_lat,
          lng: from_long
        },
        {
          lat: to_lat,
          lng: to_long
        }
      ],
      icons: [{
        icon: lineSymbol,
        repeat: '35px',
        offset: '100%'
      }],
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: linecolor,
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      map: map
    });
    bikePath.setMap(map);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was already answered in [Text Within Polyline Google Maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852326/text-within-polyline-google-maps-v3)

One solution would be using this library from github:
https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label

You could use it like this:

```
var labelPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(middle_lat, middle_long);    

var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
    text: "Your text",
    position: labelPosition ,
    map: map,
    fontSize: 12
});
```

You would have to calculate the Middle-Point between the two points.